# WiFi problem when connecting to DSL

Tags: wi-fi, samsung-galaxy-s-4

When I connect to DSL Wi-Fi it automatically disconnects and "sign into Wi-Fi network required" option appears, clicking on which opens Google only.

I tried many times to fix this problem, but I did not succeed. Can you please help me?